# Rewrite rule for mod_rewrite with query ID

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

After much googling and digging around I have the feeling I´m very close but still not getting there.

I have a URL

```
my.url.com/mymeeting.py?view=nicecompact&confId=54
```

or

```
my.url.com/myschedule.py?view=nicecompact&confId=54
```

I would like to turn this to:

```
my.otherurl.com/conf/event/54
```

In order to achieve this I want to use `mod_rewrite` to capture the number in the `confId parameter` from URL #1 and append it to the new URL #2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} confId=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^/my(meeting|schedule)\.py /conf/event/%1? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Not working. confId still gets appended to the end of new URL.

Comment: Is there a way to parse only the number and add it to /event/XX where XX is confId number? Also, can we use a wildcard in place of /my(meeting|schedule)\.py to make it /my(*)\.py? The reason for this is that besides meeting/schedule there may be others.

Comment: You can change whatever you like! What do you mean __"still gets appended"__? That's what you asked for in your question...

Comment: Thanks for your help. confId=54 gets fully appended to the end of the new URL. I need a way to append only the number, rewriting confId=54 to /event/54

Comment: Ah, I see. Check the edit, you need to pop a `?` on the end of the rewrite to force a blank query string.

Comment: Looks much better, seems like we're nearly there! Now I get point the browser to myurl.com/indico/conferenceOtherViews.py?view=nicecompact&confId=54 I get myNEWURL/indico?view=nicecompact&confId=54 . What I need is to get myNEWURL/indico/event/54

Comment: but the rewrite explicitly contains `event` so it can't be this rule that you're picking up. Also the addition of the `?` will truncate the query string entirely, further evidence this rule is not being triggered.

Comment: You were correct. There was a different rewrite rule taking precedence. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if you're happy it helped you to a solution